# Adding zeros in front of double

Tags: java, double

I have a double

ex: -2.34

I want to add 9 zeros in front of it to make length fixed to 10 digits.

Result: -0000000002.34

I tried:

```
String formatted = String.format("%010d", number);
```

But can we pass a double to the String format function?

What is the most efficient method to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a [`DecimalFormat` object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), supplying the pattern yourself.  The `0` characters indicate that a digit should be printed here, even if normally unnecessary.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0000000000.00");
String formatted = df.format(-2.34);
```

Outputting:

```
-0000000002.34
```

With `String.format`, you can supply the total length as well as any decimal characters used.  Use `14` as the total length, to account for the 10 "whole" digits, the negative sign, the decimal point, and 2 decimal digits.

```
String.format("%014.2f", test)
```

The output is:

```
-0000000002.34
```

Comment: This is a side question. Can I get the sign in front, I mean enforce sign (+/-). Is there a modification to this string format ?

Comment: Yes, include the `+` character, e.g. `String.format("%+014.2f", -2.34);`.